# Why won't this script properly sanitize output?

Tags: php

I am trying to sanitize the output of what should be a simple email script, but it only outputs a blank page. Here is the script:

```
    <?php
define("EMAIL", "info@silentpost.net");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  //include validation class
  include('./support/validate.class.php');

  //assign post data to variables
  $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $_POST['email'] = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $name = trim($_POST['name']);
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $message = trim($_POST['message']);

  //start validating our form
  $v = new validate();
  $v->validateStr($name, "name", 3, 75);
  $v->validateEmail($email, "email");
  $v->validateStr($message, "message", 5, 1000);

  if(!$v->hasErrors()) {
        $header = "From: $email\n" . "Reply-To: $email\n";
        $subject = "email from silentpost.net website!";
        $email_to = EMAIL;

        $emailMessage = "Name: " . $name . "\n";
        $emailMessage .= "Email: " . $email . "\n\n";
        $emailMessage .= $message;

        @mail($email_to, $subject ,$emailMessage ,$header );

    } else {
    //set the number of errors message
    $message_text = $v->errorNumMessage();

    //store the errors list in a variable
    $errors = $v->displayErrors();

    //get the individual error messages
    $nameErr = $v->getError("name");
    $emailErr = $v->getError("email");
    $messageErr = $v->getError("message");
  }//end error check


}// end isset
?>
```

If I omit the following code, the script will run fine:

```
$_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST['email'] = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

if necessary, I will include the class, but I don't think it is an issue with the class, as removing the filter_var lines outputs correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldnt assing the filter vars back to post. put them into the same variables you trim in the next block. Also are you sure those items actually exist in `$_POST` as strings?

Comment: You could also use `$xyz = trim(filter_var($_POST['xyz'], FILTER_...));` along with the comment from @prodigitalson. With that, `filter_var` should return `FALSE` if there's a problem, not kill the script.

Comment: yes, the items exist (the validation class checks for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do two things:

A. Make sure you're running PHP >= 5.2 (minimum for the filter_var function).

B. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the script, this will let you see what error is being thrown causing the blank page.

Comment: looks like this is the issue. I'm running 5.1.6. upgrading now, and have added the filter_var into the same vars as the trim.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is nothing wrong with the script. What is the exact issue? Does your script not send emails if you sanitize or it does not throw any output? If it's the latter, then I don't think your script is anyways producing any output.

Try echoing your content, before and after the sanitization and see if they differ:

```
echo 'BEFORE<br>';
echo $_POST['name'] . '<br>';
echo $_POST['email'] . '<br>';
echo $_POST['message'] . '<br>';

$_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST['email'] = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

echo 'AFTER<br>';
echo $_POST['name'] . '<br>';
echo $_POST['email'] . '<br>';
echo $_POST['message'] . '<br>';
```

Comment: Also check if filter_var() is returning FALSE?

Comment: looks like I'm running an older version of PHP that doesn't support filter_var... stupid mistake on my part ;)